# Adding lib64 to .gitignore doesn't ignore the directory

Tags: python, git, gitignore

Made a new virtual environment using venv.

```sh
python3 venv ./
```

It created multiple directories, one of which is a directory named lib64.
I then added all the directories created to my .gitignore file and everything is not being tracked except for the lib64 directory.

.gitignore file

```
__pycache__/

bin/
include/
lib/
lib64/
share/

*.cfg
```

Yet it still shows when I run `git status`

```sh
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    lib64
```

Comment: `lib64` appears to be a file (literally a file, not a directory / folder). Your `.gitignore` directive says to ignore files contained within any directory named `lib64`, but specifically *not* to ignore *files* named `lib64`, so this seems quite natural.

Comment: That worked... Why does it show as a directory though... `lib64/python3.8/site-packages`

Comment: What is the *it* that shows this as a directory? (My best guess is that this thing is a symlink, and whatever the "it" is that you're using, it's not symlink-aware; but Git is.)

Answer (score 0):

The lib64 folder that you see is a symbolic link, which means that it's not a real folder.
What you have to do is just add `lib64` and not `lib64/` in you gitignore as if `lib64` is a file and not a folder.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add and commit `.gitignore` first